# Find a zip file, print path and zip contents

Tags: linux, path, find, exec, unzip

I have a series of numbered sub-directories that may or may not contain zip files, and within those zip files are some single-line .txt files I need. Is it possible to use a combination of find and unzip -p to list the file path and the single line contents on the same output line? I'd like to save the results to a .txt and import it into excel to work with.

From the main directory I can successfully find and output the single line:

```
find . -name 'file.zip' -exec unzip -p {} file.txt \;
```

How can I prefix the find output (i.e. the file path) to the output of this unzip command? Ideally, I'd like each line of the text file to resemble:

```
./path/to/file1.zip    "Single line of file1.txt file"
./path/to/file2.zip    "Single line of file2.txt file"
```

and so on. Can anyone provide some suggestions? I'm not very experienced with linux command line beyond simple commands.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the code you want to execute into a shell script, then use the `exec` feature to call the shell script, i.e.

```
cat finder.bash
#!/bin/bash

printf "$@ : "   # prints just the /path/to/file/file.zip
unzip -p "$@" file.txt
```

For now, get that to work, you can make it generic to pass others besides `file.txt` later.

Make the script executable

```
chmod 755 finder.bash
```

Call it from `find`. i.e.

```
find . -name 'file.zip' -exec /path/to/finder.bash {} \;
```

(I don't have an easy way to test this, so reply in comments with error msgs).